# Optimize route SKMaps - Swift

Tags: swift, skmaps, skobbler-maps, skviapoint

I am using SKMaps to get routes with several viaPoints.

SKMaps returns routes that are much slower than Google Maps. I've tried all of the various combinations of SKRouteModes (.CarFastest, etc.), but none of them come close to Google Maps routes.

I'm thinking my viaPoints need to be optimized. Is there a way to optimize a route with viaPoints in SKMaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/8058-Optimize-routes-iOS-SDK-Swift this is not about slower routes, it is about not optimizing the order of via points - a functionality which is not supported right now by the Scout Developer Platform.